# Trigger Script in Spreadsheet in Similar Fashion to a Link

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I currently have a button on my spreadsheet (a text box image that triggers the script). Unfortunately this button doesn't work when using a tablet. Is there a way of triggering a script to run via a link or the same way you can click on a link on e field in a spreadsheet?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13004853/running-a-script-from-a-hyperlink-in-a-cell/47318974#47318974) may be a potential solution as well

Answer (score 2):

Scripts can be invoked as custom functions (e.g., `=myFunction()` entered into a cell); but when used in this way, they can only affect the cell into which they're entered. Generally, the recommended way is to use custom menu commands (as I described, e.g., [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/78120/)).

But if you really want a hyperlink, here is a way to do this. Warning: this is a kludge.

1. Add to your script the following function:

```
function params() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ssid = ss.getId();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();
  return '?ssid='+ssid+'&name='+sheetName;
}
```

2. Rename the function you want to run as `doGet` and rewrite it as follows:

```
function doGet(e) {
  var ssid = e.parameters.ssid;
  var sheetName = e.parameters.name;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssid);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);

  //   do whatever you want with this spreadsheet and sheet

  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<p>Script executed. Close this window to return to the spreadsheet.</p>');
}
```

3. [Deploy the script as a web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploying_a_script_as_a_web_app). The default parameters (run as you; only you have access) are good for this. You will get a URL of the web app.
4. In the spreadsheet, create a hyperlink with the following:

```
=HYPERLINK("https://script.google.com/macros/s/ ... /exec"&params())
```

where the URL is the web app URL that you got in step 3. This is the link that will execute the script when clicked.

Explanation:

- When running as a web app, the script does not know what spreadsheet and what sheet you are working on. This is why the function `params()` obtains these parameters and adds them to the hyperlink. The script gets them from `e.parameters` object.
- Unfortunately, clicking the hyperlink will open a new tab. That tab will not have much content (only the message "Script executed. Close this window to return to the spreadsheet.") but I can see this being an annoyance. This is why I called this a kludge.