# Passing variable to Google Apps Script Deployed web application

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am developing a spreadsheet where a user clicks a link in the sheet to call a deployed web app as described here [Trigger Script in Spreadsheet in Similar Fashion to a Link](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/78262/trigger-script-in-spreadsheet-in-similar-fashion-to-a-link/78301#78301?newreg=d8f03e03972842ae9fbe61df03c986fd)

This works well although I need to somehow identify the row of the calling cell that the user clicked the link. So if the

```
=HYPERLINK("https://script.google.com/macros/s/ ... /exec"&params())
```

Is in cell E1, I need the functions called to know the calling row is "1". I tried GetActiveCell within the params function and I keep getting a range error. I also tried passing the row directly to the params() function through the calling hyperlink and it did not receive the value [I tried as (1) and ("1")]. Is there a way to pass a value to the params function?

```
=HYPERLINK("https://script.google.com/macros/s/ ... /exec"&params(1))
```

Can anyone offer any help / suggestions? It would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the function `params` to accept the argument it's given, and use it in forming the string that it returns. Like so:

```
function params(row) {                                   // added row here
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ssid = ss.getId();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();
  return '?ssid='+ssid+'&name='+sheetName+'&row='+row;   // added row here
}
```

Now when you use `...exec" & params(1))` the value of 1 will be correctly appended to the URL used to invoke the web app: the URL will have `&row=1` and consequently, the `doGet` function of the web app will receive this value as `e.parameters.row`.

**However** it's easier to just append 1 yourself: in the hyperlink function, put

```
...exec" & params() & "&row=1" )
```

or

```
...exec" & params() & "&row=" & row() )
```

There is no need to run a number through a custom function when you can just append it to the URL in the spreadsheet. The reason the custom function `params` is needed is to pass the values that spreadsheet functions cannot access: spreadsheet id and sheet name.

Comment: Thanks Zaq. Worked great. I added a few twists. [link](=hyperlink("https://script.google.com/a/macros/a...#.org/s/A.....g/exec"&params(),concatenate(B1,", ",C1)) which puts a clickable link in the cell. Then, in the function, I dynamically determine the calling cell to get the selected row. `function params() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ssid = ss.getId();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];  
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var selRow = cell.getRowIndex();
  return '?ssid='+ssid+'&name='+sheetName+'&selRow='+selRow;
}`